# Como criar atalho de um App do Google Chrome no desktop via script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Tenho um App no Google Chrome e gostaria de colocar em meu site um link que faça com que crie um atalho no desktop do usuário. Sei que tem como criar clicando no botão direito do mouse e criar atalho, mais eu gostaria de um script que faça isso.

Em qual linguagem deveria fazer?

Comment: Javascript não acessa recursos do sistema operacional, até recursos do browsers são bem limitados. Pois se ele fizesse isso, seria uma brecha de segurança muito grande. Qualquer um poderia criar "coisas" no seu computador, como vírus entre outros por exemplo.

Comment: Então porque existe o comando de criar atalho na Área de Trabalho via web nos Apps do Chrome?

Comment: E qual é esse comando? Isso provavelmente é um recurso próprio do Chrome, não pertencendo ao Javascript.

Comment: Sim é do Chrome. Por isso perguntei se possível javascript, se nao der em Javascript tem ideia de como faria isso?

Comment: De interesse: [Creating a Desktop Shortcut Using a Web Page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427619/1287812). Encontrada [dentro desta pesquisa](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+desktop+shortcut+is%3Aquestion) que tem um outro par de coisas interessantes.